# Is a mapping library like AutoMapper available on the .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, automapper

Is anyone working on a .NET Compact Framework port of AutoMapper or are there any similar mapping libraries for the .NET Compact Framework?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052002/alternatives-to-automapper and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663577/automapper-vs-valueinjecter

Comment: and what about the valueinjecter ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build on [OmuMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781707/simple-convention-automapper-for-two-way-mapping-entities-to-from-viewmodels) ? (UPDATE: @Omu himself has since built [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com)).

(Obviously there's a strong chance this wont meet many challenges you might place in front of it. Are you really interested in all the AM features? Is size an issue? Any more context you can give?)

EDIT: As they've [RTW'd over at AutoMapper](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/GrabBagOfT/~3/jg6-LUSs120/automapper-1-0-rtw.aspx) Maybe now is the perfect time to ask the question in their forum while the eyes of the world are watching.

EDIT 2: 5 Oct 12 - AM still doesn't officially support it at present, [see this email thread with '10 and '12 contributions from @Jimmy Bogard himself](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/automapper-users/cfh0Hfe4Lz0). [... but ValueInjecter does support it (with some provisos)](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/workitem/7700)

Comment: I'm just interested in a simple mapper that works on the .NET Compact Framework. Are you going to post your mapper on Google Code / CodePlex?

Comment: @DanielO: Not sure whether you're referring to me or Omu. My answer was that I strongly believe that writing YAM is bad news for lots of reasons. On the other hand (where I have different fingers), depending on your exact usage scenario (you could elaborate in order to give us a picture of how much mapping you're doing and whether you're doing formatting and whether performance matters in your context), it may actually make sense to write something Quick And Dirty as Omu has a) shown is possible b) using. Omu posted most of his and looks open to sharing - I'd ask him.

Comment: OK. I've seen that AutoMapper has CF support in the horizon, so I'll just go with the small mapping system until then.

Comment: That's great news. The last thing you want is to be maintaining and extending something that isnt core to you.

Answer (score -1):

EmitMapper is faster

emitmapper.codeplex.com

but is is subtle hope that it can run in CF

upd: sorry, System.Reflection.Emit doesn't exist in .net cf